# How to edit a watch expression in visual studio 2008 with the keyboard?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, keyboard-shortcuts, watch

In visual studio 2008, when the focus is on a watch expression in the watch window, how can I edit this expression without double-clicking the mouse?

In visual C++ 6, it was the obvious: the <kbd>F2</kbd> key.  This is the consistent Windows behavior in listviews, e.g. for renaming a file in Explorer, editing a cell in Excel, etc.
For some reason someone decided to remove this shortcut from VS.  I can't find anything like it in the keyboard shortcuts awful little window.

This is annoying me to no end.  I DO NOT want to reach for my mouse when I'm debugging.

Answer (score 0):

This just works for me.

<kbd>F2</kbd> starts editing. It also starts editing when I just start typing any text. I'm using VS2008 C++/CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I found out what was the problem.
I had previously assigned <kbd>F2</kbd> to the `Edit.NextBookmarkInDocument` command in VS. This is the same as it was in VC6 (in VS 2003 and forward, in the "Visual C++ 6" keyboard mapping scheme, <kbd>F2</kbd> is `Edit.NextBookmark`, which goes through all the bookmarks in all the files, which I find distracting and not very useful).

When I assigned it, I assigned it in the Text Editor context only (that is, in the Keyboard shortcut windows I put "Text Editor" in the "Use New Shortcut In".

But for some reason when I'm in the watch window, pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> there takes me away from the watch window and into the text editor.  This looks like a bug to me, because I double checked and I don't have any global mapping for <kbd>F2</kbd>.

Does anyone else have any solution to this?